# Using stored procedure in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE userAanmaken
(    
IN domeinNummer INT(11),
IN gebruikerNaam VARCHAR(45),
IN gebruikerPass VARCHAR(45),
IN gebruikerEmail VARCHAR(45),
IN gebruikerVN VARCHAR(50),
IN gebruikerTV VARCHAR(10),
IN gebruikerAN VARCHAR(50),
IN gebruikerGS VARCHAR(1),
IN gebruikerOL VARCHAR(30),
IN gebruikerGD DATE
)

BEGIN 

DECLARE lastID INT;

INSERT INTO Gebruiker(Domein_idDomeint) 
VALUES (domeinNummer);

SET lastId=LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO Inlog (Gebruiker_idGebruiker,UserName,UserPass)
VALUES (lastId,gebruikerNaam,gebruikerPass);

INSERT INTO GGevens (Gebruiker_idGebruiker,Email,Voornaam,Tussenvoeg,Achternaam,Geslacht,Opleiding,GebDatum)
VALUES (lastId,gebruikerEmail,gebruikerVN,gebruikerTV,gebruikerAN,gebruikerGS,gebruikerOL,gebruikerGD);
END$$
```

Now I call the procedure with the following code:

```
CALL userAanmaken (@domeinNummer=3,@gebruikerNaam='Jansen',
@gebruikerPass='Jaap',
@gebruikerEmail='jan@piet.nl',
@gebruikerVN='Joop',
@gebruikerTV='van',
@gebruikerAN='Heha',
@gebruikerGS='M',
@gebruikerOL='Hoog',
@gebruikerGD='2011-11-11')
```

When i use this CALL it returns with the following error:

> ## 1048 - Column 'Domein_idDomeint' cannot be null

Domein_idDomeint should be "3" this is "domeinNummer INT(11)" in the procedure

Does anyone know how to fix the error :)? (Im using PHPmyadmin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it:

```
CALL userAanmaken (
3,
'piet',
'Jaap',
'rrrr@piet.nl',
'Joop',
'van',
'Heha',
```

'M',
'Hoog',
'2011-11-11')